# How to bind a datatable to drop down list in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I am very new to ASP.net MVC . I want to bind a dropdown with a datatable while the page is loading intitaally. In webforms, i used to do like:

```
dropdownname.datasource=dt;
dropdownname.textfield="name";
dropdownname.valuefield="id";
```

name and id are the column names in data table. I am using aspx view engine. Please help on this,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you looking for something like [this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/128/Get-The-Drop-On-ASP.NET-MVC-DropDownLists) ?

Answer (score 1):

In MVC you can use the HtmlHelper [`DropDownListFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Suppose you havea view model like this:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Some other properties..

    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

You can generate a dropdownlist with the helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, Model.Countries)
```

You will have to populate the country list in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int userId)
{
    var model = new UserModel();
    // get data from db.

    // Populate countries list.
    model.Countries = db.Countries.Select(c => new SelectListItem
                                                   {
                                                        Value = c.Id,
                                                        Text = c.Name
                                                   }).ToList();
}
```

If you'd wrap this dropdownlist in a form, it will post the selected country id to the controller.

There are tons of other example around on the internet. Try [this one](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/how-to-simple-html-dropdownlistfor-mvc-net/) for example. Also, Google is your best friend.